# HERE SDK display available country list

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to display all available download country list like the image

[image]

[image]

i had try the getMapPackages (), and i can get a "True" as result, but i have no idea how to perform next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you already checked the documentation.
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html

After getMapPackages() , you can show the list on UI as you like and then user selects a Package, you can pass the Id into installMapPackages() method to download the map.You will need to add listner as well as mentioned in the link above.

Hope it Helps !

Comment: do you known how can get the installed map list in offline mode, because the MapLoader.Listener will only work when connected to internet?

Answer (score 0):

As Jithin has mentioned you need to add a `MapLoader.Listener` object by way of the `MapLoader#addListener()` method. There is example code demonstrating this on the `MapLoader` documentation page. https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html

Once you have added a `MapLoader.Listener` object, when you call `MapLoader#getMapPackages()` you will get a callback to `MapLoader.Listener#onGetMapPackagesComplete`. From here you can use the returned `MapPackage` object to find the names of the packages available for installation. API documentation for the `MapPackage` object can be found here: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-odml-mappackage.html

Comment: do you known how can get the installed map list in offline mode, because the MapLoader.Listener will only work when connected to internet?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a limitation of the current solution. All operations involving the MapLoader require an internet connection. If you need to display map packages even while offline, one option is to cache the state in your app (persist it to storage). You can then show this cached state if you cannot use the MapLoader due to lack of connectivity.